# background image in bootstrap not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I put a background image for the body but for some reason when i shrink the window the image does not get smaller as the window gets smaller, so it should still take up the whole background but shrink ,

HTML: 
Just have my `body` tag

```
CSS: 

    body {
        background-image: url("../Images/c.jpg");
        padding-top: 58px;
        background-size:100% auto;
    }
```

This makes the image get smaller as the window gets smaller but it reapts at the bottom , so its like 2 of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/ishio/pen/PmVbPq) for a responsive example.

Using `background-size:cover` will cover the entire div. Using `background-size:contain` will keep the ratio and contain it within the div.

Answer (score 0):

> This makes the image get smaller as the window gets smaller but it [repeats] at the bottom , so its like 2 of them

That's because backgrounds repeat by default.  Add `background-repeat:no-repeat`

Comment: tried this already but white space appears now, image does get smaller but has white space at the bottom

Comment: @RonTheOld What do you expect the bottom to consist of?  Do you want the image to crop at the left and right edges?  That would be the `background-size:cover ` rule suggested by Ishio.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong background-size property.

You need to change your css to:

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../Images/c.jpg");
    padding-top: 58px;
    background-size:cover;
}
```